# how can I make a simple route on rails and can I use it for an ajax form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Ive been trying to create a simple route on rails, following this instructions

> http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

my problem is that when I want to enter to my method I get a weird error.

I have a controler **user** and on my routes I wrote something like this

```
resources :users do
  match "/custom/" => "user#custom"
end
```

So, at my controller I add this code

```
def custom
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
end
```

but when I try to enter doing localhost:3000/users/1/custom I get an error like

> uninitialized constant UserController

doing rake routes I can see

```
user_custom     /users/:user_id/custom(.:format)    user#custom
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

I want this route to submit a form... is it possible to use this route (if i make it run) for use ajax? I want to submit a form.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your route to:

```
resources :users do
  match "/custom/" => "users#custom"
end
```

You should avoid the use of `match` though, since it will be deprecated in Rails 4. Try this instead

```
resources :users do
  get :custom, on: :member
end
```

`get` is the verb, `:custom` the route and `on: :member` means that you are looking for a `/users/:id/custom` route instead of a `/users/custom` one. If you are looking for the latter, do this:

```
resources :users do
  get :custom, on: :collection
end
```

Comment: do i need to define an special route for submit a form for example? to incluide every variable im going to send?

Comment: No, you just send them with post instead of get ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is like this, which I prefer:

```
resources :users do
  get 'custom', on: :collection
end
```

That gives you a route of `/users/custom`.  If you were do use `on: :member`, then it would give you a route of `/users/:id/custom`.

You can also use a block for defining multiple custom actions for collections or members.

For example:

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    get 'custom'
    post 'some_other_method'
  end

  member do
    get 'some_action'
  end
end
```

Comment: the post methods work if for example I want to submit a form??

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right.  You can use either `put` or `post` depending on whether you are updating or creating a resource.